# How to do a VueJs production build that can be served directly from file system instead of a http server?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, cross-platform, vue-router

Currently the command **npm run build** produces files that requires a http server for the application to work. But that becomes a problem when one needs to wrap the entire VueJs app inside a mobile application **WebView** using Xamarin or NativeScript. Using relative paths in config/index.js ***breaks history mode of vue-router***, which again becomes a problem. Hosting the entire SPA on a server like surge or gh-pages, and loading that url inside WebView works but then the app requires active internet connection everytime it starts.

So, how can a VueJs application be wrapped inside a WebView to produce an ***offline mobile application*** ? Thanks.

Comment: For NativeScript, they have a [documentation page](https://docs.nativescript.org/best-practices/bundling-with-webpack) on this.

Comment: @EmileBergeron yes, but that seems to be for NativeScript compatible templates/features whereas my app is a full HTML SPA, parts of which is incompatible with NativeScript. That is one of the reasons I'm trying to wrap entire app inside a webview.

Comment: Maybe Cordova would be a better alternative? I know that it serves the app from a local server.

Comment: Have you looked into [Weex](https://weex.incubator.apache.org/)?

Comment: @EmileBergeron I'll have to experiment with cordova. The CSP rules didn't play very well last time I tried that. I've it as my last option.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter just like NativeScript, Weex has it's own set of components and is not 100% compatible with HTML5/CSS3.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Can you please point me to the source where it says cordova serves app using a local server instead of directly accessing it through file system ?

Comment: I don't know where to find it, I just remember from 2 years ago when I used it briefly to bundle a complex SPA.